# How to assign different colors to each list item in an HTML unordered list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I know that I can assign one color to an unordered list like this:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  padding-left: 16px;
}

li:before {
  content: "• ";
  padding-right: 8px;
  color: green;
}
```

But this change the color of all bullets. I want to assign different colors to each bullet. Can I somehow apply n-th child function for that?

Comment: use :nth-child(1) and so on

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp  -- link for reference

Comment: `:nth-child(1)` has a nice equivalent which is [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) (MDN)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple solution is;

```
li:before {
  content: "• ";
  padding-right: 5px;
  color: green;
}

li:nth-child(1):before {
  color: green;
}

li:nth-child(2):before {
  color: red;
}

li:nth-child(3):before {
  color: blue;
}
```

Or You could have a different background color for each list item,

```css
body {
  background-color: #151515;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Cuprum';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Cuprum'), local('Cuprum-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/cuprum/v4/sp1_LTSOMWWV0K5VTuZzvQ.woff) format('woff');
}

nav ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -80px;
  width: 120px;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  font: normal 1.2em/1em 'Cuprum', Candara, "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-decoration: none
}

nav li:nth-child(1) a {
  background: #2b5fd6;
}

nav li:nth-child(2) a {
  background: red;
}

nav li:nth-child(3) a {
  background: green;
}

nav li:nth-child(4) a {
  background: purple;
}

nav a img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 10px 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="navigation">
    <li>
      <a href="#home"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/BwCBz.png" width="21" height="21" alt="Home" />Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#about"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Uzj32.png" width="21" height="21" alt="About" />About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#works"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/KBt72.png" width="19" height="20" alt="Works" />Works</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#talk"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/aplDt.png" width="21" height="15" alt="Talk" />Talk</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Or you could use something called ***FontAwesome*** it replaces the bullets with images/icons. That's if you want your bullets to be fancy. [LINK](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/)

**Sample:**

[image]

```
https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css
```

**Example**

```css
ul,
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 2em 0;
}

li {
  margin: 1em;
  margin-left: 3em;
}

li:before {
  content: '\f012';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  float: left;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
  color: #0074D9;
}

.link {
  font-size: 0.45em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul>
  <li>Net 10%</li>
  <li>Net 20%</li>
  <li>Net 30%</li>
  <li>Net 40%</li>
  <li>Net 50%</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

CSS

```
li:nth-child(1):before {
  content: "• ";
  padding-right: 8px;
  color: green;
}
```

and so on
change number as you need

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible through the css rule nth-child. Use some rules like:

```
li:nth-child(1):before {
  color: red;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/motou/pen/vZpERy

If you want to change the bullet color randomly, then you need javascript to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
li:before {
content: "• ";
padding-right: 8px;
}

ul li:nth-child(n) 
{ 
color:pink;
 }
ul li:nth-child(n+1) 
{ 
color:white;
 }
```

You can change it for odd and even number bullets by the below code:

```
   ul li:nth-child(odd) 
    { 
    color:pink;
     }
    ul li:nth-child(even) 
    { 
    color:white;
     }
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this with your css:

```
li:nth-child(2):before{
      color:red;
      }
      li:nth-child(3):before{
      color:yellow;
      }
```